# error: void value not ignored as it ought to be

Tags: c++, function-pointers, dlsym

I am trying to get function symbol from a dynamic library and then I need to replace my function with the library funciton using the new function pointer.The code is to be written in c++ file.

I used following steps,

```
{
void *temp = dlsym(<FLAGS>,<FUNC_NAME>);
*reinterpret_cast<void**>(&real_mal) = temp;
void *p = NULL;
p = real_mal(size);
return p;
}
```

But at compile time I am getting this "error: void value not ignored as it ought to be " error

How can I resolve above situation ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the definition of `real_mal`? And on what line do you get the error?

Comment: @joachim-the defination isstatic void (*real_mal) (size_t size) = 0;

Comment: Instead of the `void` return value, shouldn't it be `void *`? So `void *(*real_mal)(size_t)` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Joachim's comment is right. The first problem is actually your cast. The proper cast is
`real_mal = reinterpret_cast<void*(size_t)>(dlsym(<FLAGS>,<FUNC_NAME>));`. Your current cast hides the incorrect declaration of `real_mal`.

Once you've fixed that, you can just write `return real_mal(size);`.